# Content Database Size in Increasing from 2003 to 2007 to 2010 to 2013

Tags: content-migration

we are migrating from SP2003 to 2013,In 2003 DB size is 3GB same data base moved to SP2007 having the DB size 3.7GB and in SP2010 5 GB in SP2013 having 7GB.

Can any one explain why the same content Database size is changing from 2003 to 2013.

Answer (score 1):

The database schema is enhanced in newer versions also more features are incorporated. It's not only the data that get stored, there will be setting etc.

Hence the increase in size.

In layman's term, data that is represented in 2003  and 2013 are different.